# google-direction API : Sometimes google provides different miles for the same set of locations

Tags: google-directions-api

I am using Google-Directions API and facing a very strange issue that at different time of the day this api returns the different value for distance for the same set of location. I am using this distance to calculate the pricing , and because of this issue my application shows different pricing for the same set of origin and destination location.

So is there any solution or parameter which i can use to make sure that google will return the same distance for same set of locations during any time of the day?

Comment: If you've already calculated a value for a specific set of locations, why not cache it, save on the API call and return it directly?

Comment: Thanks Jonathan for a prompt reply. Even i was thinking of this solution but before implementing this i was just confirming if google directions or any other api is having any such type of feature where it can assure to return same result.